# How to allow zero values in html input type date for month and date

Tags: html

I need to able to send zero values in html input type date,

like 2017-0-0 or 2017-4-0

by default it is not allowing me to enter zero, if i leave month or date empty it says "*Please enter a valid value. The field is incomplete or has an invalid date*"

Comment: `2017-0-0` isn't a valid date. You'll need to stop using a date `input` element if you want to handle non-date values.

Comment: Do you want other fields in form to be validated

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use regular expression to validate your input...
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "zero value" or any other invalid value for month and date in `<input type="date">`. If you really want to use `2017-0-0` or `2017-4-0`, either use plain `<input type="text">`, or use third-party date library and enable "zero value" by changing its source code.

For "zero value" issue, [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#date-state-(type=date)) explicitly declare that invalid date string should not be allowed:

> User agents must not allow the user to set the value to a non-empty string that is not a valid date string.

By [valid date string](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-month-string), it means:

- Four or more ASCII digits, representing year, where year > 0
- Two ASCII digits, representing the month, in the range 1 ≤ month ≤ 12
- Two ASCII digits, representing day, in the range 1 ≤ day ≤ maxday where maxday is the number of days in the month and year